# Create bold column names (colnames) when writing to excel file in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm trying to make my column name bold but I haven't found any answer. I created a sheet and added the columns names with `colnames`. And now I would like to make those new names bold, this is my code:

```
    file0<-read_excel("path", sheet=1)
tempermax <- read.csv("path")
tempmaxima <- rbind(file0,tempermax)
tempmaxima$Fecha <-as.Date(tempmaxima$Fecha, "%d/%m/%y") 
tempmaxima <- unique(tempmaxima)
colnames(tempmaxima)<- c("Fecha", "Temperatura_máxima_°_C")

write.xlsx(tempmaxima, file="path", 
           sheetName = 'Temperatura máxima', row.names = T, col.names = T)
```

Comment: If you use the `asTable = TRUE` args to `openxlsx::write.xlsx`, the headers are bolded.

Comment: @David T, thanks, worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a custom header style with the package `openxlsx`:

```
library(openxlsx)
workbook <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(workbook, "mtcars")
bold.style <- createStyle(textDecoration = "Bold")
writeData(workbook, "mtcars", mtcars, startRow = 1, startCol = 1,
          headerStyle = bold.style)
openXL(workbook)
```

[image]

See the [formatting guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/formatting.pdf) from the package for more info.

Comment: I added the openxlsx library and now write.xlsx is not writting new worksheets in my code with append = TRUE. I was using xlsx library, i don't know if open is not letting xlsx library to use append.

Comment: If you're having trouble with two packages breaking each other, you can always restart your R session to fix that problem.